# Getting Pixel Information From CGImage and Change it with Swift 4

Tags: swift

The thing is I can get pixel information with following code but can not write back.

```
    var pixelsCopy:[UInt8] = []
    let data: NSData = cgImage!.dataProvider!.data!  
    var pixels  = data.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)


 while index < widthOfImage * heightOfImage * 4 {
    pixelsCopy.append( pixels[index] )   
    pixelsCopy.append( pixels[index + 1] )  
    pixelsCopy.append( pixels[index + 2] )
    pixelsCopy.append( pixels[index + 3] )
  index += 4
}
```

With writing back I mean something like following

```
   pixels[index] = newRedValue
```

I am having "subscript get-only" error.
We could do it at Obj-C as much as I recall.

Comment: Change `let` to `var`.

Comment: @maddy var is not working, I tried.

Comment: I did not understand why this question is down voted. Because later I have been able to change the pixels in specific location in an image and manipulate the image as I wished.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of answer.

I could not change pixels arrays but I created pixelsCopy array played RGB and Alpha values of that array then created first a CGImage then to an UIImage.

But sometimes final images has becoming distorted I do not know why at the moment.

To convert pixelsCopy array to CGImage I used this code

```
    let numComponents = 4
    let lenght = givenImageWidth * givenImageHeight * numComponents
    let bitmapInfo  = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)

    let colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB() 
    let rgbData = CFDataCreate(nil, pixelsCopy, lenght)!
    let provider = CGDataProvider(data: rgbData)!
    let rgbImageRef = CGImage(width: size_w,
                              height: size_h,
                              bitsPerComponent: 8,
                              bitsPerPixel: 8 * numComponents,
                              bytesPerRow: givenImageWidth * numComponents,
                              space: colorspace,
                              bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo,
                              provider: provider,
                              decode: nil,
                              shouldInterpolate: true,
                              intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)!

    let finalUIImage = UIImage(cgImage: rgbImageRef)

    anImageView.image = finalUIImage

    pixelsCopy.removeAll()
```

If you want to see good and and distorted images check out the R letters at the bottom of images below.

The R on the left is the given image the one at the right is my finalUIImage image.

[image: Shows the images]

Comment: I noticed that distortion happens if the UIImage size changes non stop (I am getting original image from captureOutput stream though it is 5 fps). If the size of the image stabilizes distortion ends.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write pixels back to a `CGImage`. A `CGImage` is read-only. You need to:

1. Create a `CGContext`.
2. Draw the image into it.
3. Draw whatever you want on top of the image.
4. Ask the context to create a new image.

Comment: I wonder which one is more expensive (takes more time) your way (which is the right one I think), or creating second array and using it like I did above.

Comment: By the way I was not trying to write back CGImage I was trying to change pixels array values.